# Examples of toposes in which the Axiom of Determinacy holds.

Tags: category-theory, set-theory, examples-counterexamples, axioms, topos-theory

I just stumbled upon [the Axiom of Determinacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_determinacy) which is an axiom in set theory - inconsistent with the Axiom of Choice, consistent with the Axiom of Dependent Choice, that states that for every subset $A \subset \mathbb N^\mathbb N$, every game between two players of the form:

"In an alternatig fashion, each player picks a natural number $a_n$ to form a sequence $(a_0, a_1, a_2 , \dots)$. Player one wins if this sequence is an element of $A$, Player two wins if the contrary is the case."

the resulting game is decidable.

Reading the known consequences for this the first time gave me an almost bizarre feeling:

> Every subset of the reals is measurable, has the Baire property and the perfect set property.

It sounds like a [measure theorists dream](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/dream+mathematics). There are some more resources in this [nice answer on overflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/129036/counterintuitive-consequences-of-the-axiom-of-determinacy).

Now, I am one of those people who only really get comfortable with set-theoretic axioms when seeing an example of a topos having said property:

**Are there known examples of toposes (elementary, having a natural numbers object) satisfying the Axiom of Determinacy?**

Comment: Axiom of Dependent Choice or Axiom of Determinancy?? And of course: *A* topos of sets and functions satisfies both axioms, as you stated.

Comment: I edited the text just before submitting, and this what happens when one does that... Axiom of Determinacy, of course. Thank you for pointing it out!

Comment: Won't a Boolean topos defined from a model of ZF+AD be an example? In any case, the consistency of AD requires quite the large cardinals.

Comment: Of course it will, but that is everything but insightful. When someone asks for an example of an irrational number and you tell him "There's countably many rationals and uncountably many reals, therefore I can give you uncountably many examples of irrational numbers" he wouldn't be satisfied either, right?

Comment: Then again, I'm not too familiar with modeltheory and maybe there's more insight to get out of the construction than I give you credit for. I appreciate the help though, don't get me wrong.

Comment: I am particularly unfamiliar with toposes, which is why I can't really help any more than just that. The proof of consistency of AD is not trivial either (in any of its forms), so I can't help much more than that. In any case as I remarked these proofs require some nontrivial large cardinal assumptions, and they use them in very substantial way. So I'm not so sure how you can "easily" come up with such examples.

Comment: Maybe I'm asking too much; the few topoi I know satisfying the Axiom of Choice for example are FinSet, Sets and the Cohen Topos, the latter two satisfying it "by definition". It would have been sweet to see a classifying topos for a certain geometric theory, or a specific grothendieck topos on a site.

Comment: I can guess what are FinSet and Sets, but I have no idea what Cohen is in this context. If $V\models\sf ZFC+\exists\omega\text{ Woodin cardinals with a measurable above them}$, then $L(\Bbb R)^V\models\sf ZF+DC+AD$. This is not trivial, of course. But that is the basic way to obtain a model of Determinacy. There are other so-called natural models for Determinacy which are quite natural if you've trudged through the long road leading to them (there is no royal road to determinacy, I'm afraid). Whether or not you can actually get any geometric intuition from $L(\Bbb R)$ and the topos it defines?

Comment: That I don't know. But I'm also more or less the last person to ask about geometric intuition... So again I'm not being useful at all. :-)

Comment: Could you give some sources/textbooks explaining your notation? I'd like to know some more about it. The Cohen topos is the topos Paul Cohen (implicitely) constructed to show the negation of the continuum hypothesis is consistent with ZFC. It's in Maclane/Moerdijk Sheaves in Geometry and Logic, Chapter VI.2. Also something interesting I found there: Sheaves on any poset with respect to the double negation topology satisfy the Axiom of Choice (Of course, assuming your Set theory satisfies it beforehand)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I wasn't notified on your comments (next time, you should use `@Asaf` to make sure I get notified). Which notation confuses you?

Comment: I'm familiar with the double turnstile, however I do not know what is meant by $L(\mathbb R)$ or $L(\mathbb R)^V$. @AsafKaragila

Comment: So $L$ is the smallest transitive class which contains all the ordinals and satisfies the axioms of ZF, so it's a canonical way to produce models of ZF (in fact ZFC and more). When we write $L(A)$ we mean the smallest transitive class such that $A$ is an element of it, and satisfies ZF. So $L(\Bbb R)$ will be the smallest model of ZF which knows about all the real numbers. It turns out that this is a model where every set is definable from finitely many reals in a somewhat canonical way. To write $L(\Bbb R)^V$ means that we "calculate" this model inside $V$, which is a given model of ZF.

Comment: (The last part matters because different models of ZF might have different sets of real numbers. And so we might be interested in several models which know about different sets of reals, so it might make an actual difference whether or not we do this construction inside one model or another.)